# How to creat clock visualization with a dynamic circle outside the clock?

Tags: python, dataframe, graph, plotly, data-visualization

[image]

I want to create a clock visualization like above pic. A dynamic line will show power consumption by time using colors. I want to put an imageof a device on this line graphs moves by time and color changes according to power value. Can anybody help me with this? I am sharing a small dataset below.

```
data= {'device': {0: 'Laptop', 1: 'Laptop', 2: 'Laptop', 3: 'Laptop', 4: 'Laptop'},
      'power': {0: 60, 1: 23, 2: 120, 3: 22, 4: 49},
      'time': {0: '16/11/2012 11:29',
      1: '16/11/2012 12:30',
      2: '16/11/2012 13:31',
      3: '16/11/2012 14:32',
      4: '16/11/2012 15:33'},
      'time_string': {0: '16/11/2012 11:29',
      1: '16/11/2012 11:30',
      2: '16/11/2012 11:31',
      3: '16/11/2012 11:32',
      4: '16/11/2012 11:33'},
      'x': {0: 0.17, 1: 0.17, 2: 0.17, 3: 0.17, 4: 0.17},
      'y': {0: 0.48, 1: 0.48, 2: 0.48, 3: 0.48, 4: 0.48}}
```

Answer (score 0):

- you have not provided much to go on
- you can dynamically build images.  Use high school trig to place and image around an image based on hour
- this can then all be integrated into a **plotly** figure which is implied from the tags you applied to question
- I did find that `add_layout_image()` does not work for date / time axes

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw
import requests, math
from io import BytesIO


def make_circle(im, buffer=0):
    x, y = im.size
    size = min(x, y)
    new_im = Image.new("RGBA", (size, size))
    new_im.paste(im, (int((size - x) / 2), int((size - y) / 2)))
    mask = Image.new("L", (size, size), 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    draw.ellipse((0, 0) + (size, size), fill=255, outline=0, width=buffer)
    new_im.putalpha(mask)
    return new_im


def hour_to_angle(hour, degree=False):
    angle = hour * (360 / 12) - 90
    return angle if degree else math.radians(angle)


url = [
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/28/21/39/cartoon-2898206__480.png",
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/03/09/10/05/laptop-6081424_1280.png",
]

# fmt: off
data= {'device': {0: 'Laptop', 1: 'Laptop', 2: 'Laptop', 3: 'Laptop', 4: 'Laptop'},
      'power': {0: 60, 1: 23, 2: 120, 3: 22, 4: 49},
      'time': {0: '16/11/2012 11:29',
      1: '16/11/2012 12:30',
      2: '16/11/2012 13:31',
      3: '16/11/2012 14:32',
      4: '16/11/2012 15:33'},
      'time_string': {0: '16/11/2012 11:29',
      1: '16/11/2012 11:30',
      2: '16/11/2012 11:31',
      3: '16/11/2012 11:32',
      4: '16/11/2012 11:33'},
      'x': {0: 0.17, 1: 0.17, 2: 0.17, 3: 0.17, 4: 0.17},
      'y': {0: 0.48, 1: 0.48, 2: 0.48, 3: 0.48, 4: 0.48}}
# fmt: on

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"]).dt.hour

fig = px.scatter(df, x="time", y="power")

# marker that is placed on image based on time
im_marker = make_circle(Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(url[1]).content)))
im_marker.thumbnail(size=(50, 50))
for i, (x, y) in df[["time", "power"]].iterrows():
    im = make_circle(Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(url[0]).content)), buffer=50)
    theta = hour_to_angle(x)
    r = int(im.size[0] * 0.45)
    c = im.size[0] // 2
    im.paste(
        im_marker,
        (
            int(c + math.cos(theta) * r) - im_marker.size[0] // 2,
            int(c + math.sin(theta) * r) - im_marker.size[0] // 2,
        ),
        im_marker,
    )

    # size custom image based on power and add to figure
    fig.add_layout_image(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        source=im,
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        sizex=y,
        sizey=y,
        xanchor="center",
        yanchor="middle",
    )

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_range=[10, 16],
    yaxis_range=[0, 140],
    template="plotly_white",
)
```

[image]